# Error: Unable to import package 'kivy_gradient.Gradient', while trying to run the exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: windows, kivy, pyinstaller, exe, executable

I imported `#:import Gradient kivy_gradient.Gradient` in my .kv file. The app is working fine without any error.
When I try to convert the file to exe using pyinstaller using : `pyinstaller --hidden-import kivy_gradient.Gradient main.py -w`. Then modifying my specs file as:

1. from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
2. a.datas += [('Code\filename.kv','location\filename.kv','DATA')]
3. Tree('folder_location')
4. *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]
   And finally building my exe file using `pyinstaller main.spec -y` command.
   When I try to run the exe file it show the error: Unable to import package 'kivy_gradient.Gradient'. Please help me, I have been struggling for long.

Comment: kivygradient is a separate package from Kivy.  have you installed it with "python -m pip install kivygradient"
?

Comment: Yes kivygradient is already installed and is working. It is only when  I create the exe file using pyinstaller, it show this error.